# TFS Custom Build Task, Powershell script shows additional blank lines in log

Tags: powershell, tfsbuild

When running a custom build task that includes a powershell script, there will be additional blank lines in my log. 
How it looks like:
[image: two additional blank lines between "Write-Host"'s.]

My Powershell Skript:

```
Write-Host "# #############Run SQL Script############# #"
Write-Host "Instance of the Database Server: $Database_ServerInstance"
Write-Host "FilePath of the SQLScript: $Script_FilePath"
```

How do I get rid of the additional blank lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write

```
Write-host “hello”
```

You actually get :

```
'hello' | Out-Default | Out-Host
```

PowerShell will apply the default formatting (which can be altered by configuration files on the host) to Out-default and the again to out-host (display in our case) .
Even worst, the formatting rules are different among versions and for desktop and server PowerShell.

try with `write-output` to see if you get different formatting.